# Xcode blocked at “Attaching to (app name)” when I launch my app in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I know there's a lot of posts with the same that problem. I just spent at least 2 hours to read them and I tried everything I saw in the responses but it still doesn't work. I don't know what to do anymore. Can someone help me?
I use Xcode 4.2.1

Comment: I have the same problem and it all started when I started playing with executable names and target names. Is it the same for you?

Comment: well I don't remember how I triggered that issue but I solved it by recreating the whole project + copy/paste the sources files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs regularly for me, and the solution was always to kill the process named `SimulatorBridge`.

And to simplify the solution you can add a custom 'behavior' in Xcode to do the task by following these steps:

1. Make a shell script file with this command:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   killall SimulatorBridge
   ```
2. Save it in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Behaviors/` as `KillSimulatorBridge.sh`.
3. Open Xcode > Preferences > Behaviors, and add a new behavior to run the shell script:
   [image: Adding custom behavior]

Now, you can run this behavior whenever Xcode hangs while trying to attach to your app, and you can even have a keyboard shortcut to run it.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yeah, with the simulator running, open Activity Monitor, find the IOS Simulator and expand it, expand the two subtasks, and kill SimultorBridge under one of them.  Then respond to the popups saying kill the simulator.  On restart it seems OK.  (No sign of SimulatorBridge if the simulator isn't running.)

Answer (score 1):

It can also happen when a different user account has the simulator running on the same computer. In that case, close the simulator on the other user's account and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer.

The simulator sometimes gets stuck and this is the only way I know to reset it. The same thing can happen to the device as well and you just have to switch it off and on again.

If that doesn't work, you may have to reinstall the SDK.

Comment: I already restart xcode, the simulator, my computer, kill the gdb process etc. This is crazy. I'm gonna reinstall everything like you said...

Comment: actually I don't have the problem with another project so I think the project configuration is in question.